# Cycle through Excel row and check value with powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I am trying to figure out the best way to achieve the following.

A script that will use an already open instance of Excel which I am using the code below:-

`$objExcel = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Excel.Application') $objExcel.Visible = $True $WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($xlSrc) $worksheet = $WorkBook.sheets.Item($strSheetName)`

This works and successfully uses the open instance of Excel and selects the required worksheet.

However I need the script to be able to cycle through column A for each row i.e. A1, A2, A3 etc... and check the value of that cell to see if it matches a pre defined variable

Once it finds a match, it then needs to cycle through the column's of that row i.e. finds match on row A6, I then need to read all values in cells A6, B6, C6 etc.... and put those values into variables for further use.

So in short, search row A until value -eq $variable. Once match is found, cycle through columns and use values as variables.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks

I did try using ImportExcel to try to pass the values to an array but couldn't get it to work. Also tried multiple methods but cant seem to get it to work how i need it to.

Searched as much as i could but couldn't find a definitive answer. Ended up trying snippets of multiple suggestions but couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible = $False
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($filepath)
$WorkSheet = $objExcel.WorkSheets.item($sheetname)
$WorkSheet.activate()

[int]$lastRow = $WorkSheet.UsedRange.rows.count
for ($i = 1; $i -le $lastRow; $i++) {
    $value = $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($i, 1).Value2
    if ($value -eq $variable) {
        [int]$lastColumn = $WorkSheet.UsedRange.columns.count
        $arr = @()
        for ($j = 0; $j -lt $lastColumn; $j++) {
            $arr[$j] = $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($i, $j + 1).Value2
        }
    }
}
```

You get an array *$arr* consisting of values in a row whose first element is *$variable*

Comment: Hi Re1ter, Thanks for your reply. I will give it a go and report back!. Thanks for taking the time to put this together.

Comment: Hi Re1ter, I am getting the following error 'Unexpected token '[$j]' in expression or statement.' - Missing Type Name after '['

Comment: Remove the space `$arr [$j]` --> `$arr[$j]`

Comment: *smh* thanks Theo!

Comment: Corrected a mistake in the answer

Comment: Hi Reiter, Your code has gotten me somewhere which is positive. I did have to change the line - [int]$lastColumn = $WorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count (included the 's' on column) otherwise it would just count 1. However, on this line $arr[$j] = $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($i, $j).Value2 i am getting the following error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC (which i think is because it cant find a value) is that because $j = 0? Therefore there is no '0' column or do Excel columns start at 0 and not 1?

Comment: Really, I hadn't thought of that. Array numbering in PowerShell starts at 0 and in Excel at 1. You need to change the line as follows: `$arr[$j] = $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($i, $j + 1).Value2`

Comment: When using the new code '$arr[$j] = $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($i, $j + 1).Value2' i get the following error "Index was outside the bounds of the array". 

This maybe due to the 0 & 1 mismatch from Excel to Powershell...?

Comment: Do you have the same number of columns in different rows?

Comment: Yes. 200 rows with 29 columns in each

Comment: Got it working. I used an ArrayList and then used $arr.add(some value). I did also have merged cells in the Excel sheet which may have been an issue, so i removed the merged cells.

Thanks for all your input/help!